# Locating core data's myApp.sqlite file for Xcode

Tags: xcode, sqlite, core-data

Where can I find the core data's .sqlite file in my mac?

I tried looking into Application Support folder but there is no iPhone simulator folder in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the application in the simulator then the sqlite file will be created wherever you define it (probably in the documents directory) to be saved in the sandbox.  You can use a simple unix command to find it:

```
find ~/Library | grep -i ${YOURFILE}.sqlite
```

If that does not show you the path then it probably hasn't been created.